# How to re-energize gemstones?

Tags: scripture, rituals, astrology

I want to know the procedure of re-energizing the gemstones. We wear them for long time so should we re-energize them from time to time? If so then how should we do that?

Comment: You have to do a "Shodhana" or purification each time you re-wear them but re-energizing them is not required as far as I know.